# How to use radio buttons to change variable values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding and am trying to use HTML5 & JavaScript to create an educational simulation with user input.

To limit input to sensible values I'd like to use 3 radio buttons to choose between Air, Water & Oil.

Each of these needs to be associated with a viscosity value & a density value which are used later on in the simulation. I've only seen so far how to use the "value" attribute of a radio button as its output, but seeing as I need two outputs tied to each button how could I acheive this (outputs are sent to two spans whose innerHTML are taken by `getElementById().innerHTML` later in the script.

```
<div class="radio">
    <p><b>Fluid Type</b></p>
<form id="fluidForm">
    <p>
        <label>Air:   <input type="radio" name="fluid" value="Air"   /></label>
        <label>Water: <input type="radio" name="fluid" value="Water" /></label>
        <label>Oil:   <input type="radio" name="fluid" value="Oil"   /></label>
    </p>
</form>

<span>Fluid viscosity:</span>
    <span id="param3">4500</span>&nbsp;Pa s
<br/>
<span>Fluid density:</span>
    <span id="param4">4500</span>&nbsp;kg/m^3 <!-- SI -->

<script>

document.getElementByName("fluid").addEventListener("change", radioChange);
document.getElementByNAme("fluid").addEventListener("click", radioChange);

function radioChange (){
    if (document.getElementByName("fluid").value = "Air"){
        document.getElementById("param3").innerHTML = 50;
        document.getElementById("param4").innerHTML = 100;
    };
    if (document.getElementByName("fluid").value = "Water"){
        document.getElementById("param3").innerHTML = 60;   
        document.getElementById("param4").innerHTML = 110;
    };
    if (document.getElementByName("fluid").value = "Oil"){
        document.getElementById("param3").innerHTML = 70;
        document.getElementById("param4").innerHTML = 120;
    };
};

//and further down variables are called:

var viscosity = document.getElementById("param3").innerHTML;
var fdensity = document.getElementById("param4").innerHTML;

    </script>
```

This doesn't seem to work, and seems to me (a total newbie) to be a blunt way of going about things anyway.

(The values inside the spans already are just place holders to let me know if it changes properly).

Huge thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: By doing this `var viscosity = document.getElementById("param3").innerHTML;
var fdensity = document.getElementById("param4").innerHTML;` you will always get initial value in both the variable

Comment: `if (document.getElementByName("fluid").value = "Air"){` are u using `=` instead of `==` or `===` in condition statement?

Comment: Would you be OK in using jQuery?

Comment: It should be document.getElementsByName (plural). It returns a NodeList of matching elements.

Comment: if you want to use document.getElementByName you have to notice that you may be find multiple element, so the actually action is getElementsByName only ID can use getElementById

Comment: And why you are getting value multiple times just get and put in a variable and use it later; and same you are doing with `.innerHTML` put `param3` and `param4` values in variables and at the end of function assign using `innserHTML`

Comment: html5 has data attributes which seems to be a solution. https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work after some changes :

1. The `getElementByName()` function doesn't exist it should be  `getElementsByName()` (note the `s` in `Elements`).
2. You should loop through the list of nodes returned by `getElementByName()` and attach event to every node :

   ```
   var fluids = document.getElementsByName("fluid");
   for(var i=0;i<fluids.length;i++){
        fluids [i].addEventListener("change", radioChange);
        fluids [i].addEventListener("click", radioChange);
   }
   ```
3. You have to define your variables in global scope and override them inside `radioChange()` method with new values.
4. You have to use `==` of `===` when you want to compare instead of `=` that should be used for affectation purpose.

Hope this helps, check working example below.

```js
var viscosity = document.getElementById("param3").innerHTML;
var fdensity = document.getElementById("param4").innerHTML;

// Attaching events HERE
var fluids = document.getElementsByName("fluid");
for(var i=0;i<fluids.length;i++){
  fluids[i].addEventListener("change", radioChange);
}

function radioChange (){
  var current_value = this.value;
  var param3 = document.getElementById("param3");
  var param4 = document.getElementById("param4");
  
  if (current_value == "Air"){
    param3.innerHTML = 50;
    param4.innerHTML = 100;
  };
  if (current_value == "Water"){
    param3.innerHTML = 60;   
    param4.innerHTML = 110;
  };
  if (current_value == "Oil"){
    param3.innerHTML = 70;
    param4.innerHTML = 120;
  };

  viscosity = param3.innerHTML;
  fdensity = param4.innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <p>
    <b>Fluid Type</b>
  </p>
  <form id="fluidForm">
    <p>
      <label>Air:   <input type="radio" name="fluid" value="Air"   /></label>
      <label>Water: <input type="radio" name="fluid" value="Water" /></label>
      <label>Oil:   <input type="radio" name="fluid" value="Oil"   /></label>
    </p>
  </form>

  <span>Fluid viscosity:</span>
  <span id="param3">4500</span>&nbsp;Pa s
  <br/>
  <span>Fluid density:</span>
  <span id="param4">4500</span>&nbsp;kg/m^3 <!-- SI -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, the simulation is now running! I understand most of your script except the use of `this` and the significance of the `current_value` variable. Would you mind explaining these to me?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont try a switch case? 
switch( fluid) {
    case air:
        param3 = ..
        param4 = ..
        break;
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block
}

Comment: Can you implement solution with `switch`?

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't against using jQuery, this is how I'd do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/danhaswings/n4hg901u/

I'd give my inputs IDs, and then use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function radioChange(id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 'air':
                alert('air');
                break;
            case 'water':
                alert('water');
                break;
            case 'oil':
                alert('oil');
                break;
            default:
                alert('undefined id');
                break;
        }
    };

    $radios = $('.radio input');

    $radios.on('change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        radioChange($this.prop('id'));
    });

});
```

This is quite easy to do without jQuery, as people have already stated above. I just thought this could be useful for you to see how it could look using jQuery.

Comment: Be carful there's no jquery tag in the OP.

Comment: This is a suggestion and doesn't answer the OP directly .. This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment.